# How to limit Windows 7 x64 to 1 CPU core?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, multi-processor

How can I limit Windows 7 x64 to use only one core of one CPU?

I already tried [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/66504-processors-limit-number-used-windows-7-a.html) and rebooted but it seemed to have no effect. Task Manager still shows four columns that were all in use from time to time, and Device Manager still showed all 4 cores. And my BIOS setup does not have any option I can tweak.

(I have an Intel Core i5 520M.)

Comment: why dp you want to do this?

Comment: @soandos: Testing purposes.

Comment: @soandos Is this question obscure?

Comment: no... why would it be...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Never mind!

Silly me -- I had adjusted the setting for Windows 8 instead of Windows 7 in `msconfig`!
Selecting the correct OS and setting the maximum number of processors definitely works.

Comment: Better to answer the question here rather than making a comment. (Answer being: MSConfig | Boot | Advanced Options | Select Number of Processor.)

Comment: @kinokijuf: Not until tomorrow :P

Answer (score 2):

Some PCs have a setting in the BIOS setup to disable all but a single core.

Also, if it's just a single program / process that you need to test, you could instead just set the processor affinity of that process. See: [How to limit a process to a single CPU core?](https://superuser.com/questions/309617/how-to-limit-a-process-to-a-single-cpu-core)

Comment: No, I need it for the whole system. That's why I didn't ask for a single process.

Comment: Er, whoops, you already mentioned the lack of BIOS setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Number of Processors or Cores to be Used in Windows 7 using `MSConfig`.

> You can find the all settings under the Boot tab in System
>   Configuration, click on the Advanced options button.

Check this link [[How to Set the Number of Processors or Cores to be Used by Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/66504-processors-limit-number-used-windows-7-a.html)] for step by step information.

If it does not work then try to do this:

```
 Type bcdedit /set onecpu on on a command prompt
    Reboot the system.
    When you are done playing, type 2 - Type: bcdedit /set onecpu off and reboot again.
```

that i got on SuperUser [question](https://superuser.com/questions/309617/how-to-limit-a-process-to-a-single-cpu-core).