# Limit Windows system to a single core

Tags: windows, cpu-cores, affinity

(This is a theoretical example:) I have a processor with 2 cores. I need to run a very CPU intensive, but strictly single-cored application as fast as possible. Is it possible to configure the Operating System (Windows) to run on one core, then run the application on another?

I'm aware you can change the "Affinity" of processes via programs like the Task Manager or [Process Lasso](https://bitsum.com/), but I'm not aware of a way to do this to system tasks. I've tried running both programs with the "SYSTEM" account, but that is still not sufficent to affect all system tasks.

I'm also aware that you can disable cores under "System Configuration", but this doesn't work for the given theoretical example.

Comment: What you want is impossible. You are not given the necessary tools to limit the NT kernel to a single core.

Comment: I agree. Further - opinions on theory like this are off topic.

Comment: IIRC, core selection is done during application programming.

Comment: Msconfig in Windows 10 still has the option to limit Windows to a specific number of cores. https://superuser.com/questions/361841/how-to-limit-windows-7-x64-to-1-cpu-core

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit Windows 7 x64 to 1 CPU core?](https://superuser.com/questions/361841/how-to-limit-windows-7-x64-to-1-cpu-core)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! The first guy unfortunately seems to be right though. Everyone else is pointing at that thing you do in system configuration, but you can't limit specific apps with that method. The goal was to limit the OS to a group of cores so that the remaining cores could be exclusively used for another application, without interrupts or extra load. With system config, NOTHING can use the disabled cores. I'm not sure how to mark comments as answers, but that first one's it.