# How to start a program with command line arguments on Windows' cmd with 'start' command?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, command-line-arguments

I need to start a program (virtual machine) in the background with a `start` command on Windows' 7 command line. Normally you would do this like that:

```
start /b cmd yourprogram
```

But I need to pass some arguments and when I so it like this (without `/b` flag to see the debug information):

```
start C:\Users\USER>start "c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe" -startvm "debian604 64"
```

I get this error message:

> Windows cannot find '-startvm'. Make sure you typed the name
>   correctly, and then try again.

On the other hand when I do it in the current command line window without the `start` in the beginning the virtual machine runs normally - but in the foreground.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
start /b "" "c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe" -startvm "debian604 64"
```

If you read the parameter list with `start /?`:

```
START ["title"] [/D path] [/I] [/MIN] [/MAX] [/SEPARATE | /SHARED]
      [/LOW | /NORMAL | /HIGH | /REALTIME | /ABOVENORMAL | /BELOWNORMAL]
      [/NODE <NUMA node>] [/AFFINITY <hex affinity mask>] [/WAIT] [/B]
      [command/program] [parameters]

    "title"     Title to display in window title bar.
    command/program
                If it is an internal cmd command or a batch file then
                the command processor is run with the /K switch to cmd.exe.
                This means that the window will remain after the command
                has been run.

                If it is not an internal cmd command or batch file then
                it is a program and will run as either a windowed application
                or a console application.

    parameters  These are the parameters passed to the command/program.
```

It expects a `title` enclosed in quotes (`"`). Since your program path included quotes, it got interpreted as the title. Adding an explicit title (in this case, empty, `""`) works.

---

An alternative method is using the `/d` switch to specify the path. Specifically:

```
start /b /d "c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\" VBoxHeadless.exe -startvm "debian604 64"
```

It appears to take the first argument after the `/d` switch as the path, even if it is quoted, and if the next argument is not quoted then this works. Everything after what is recognised as the command/program is passed as a parameter to that command/program. Note this will not work if the command/program has spaces in the name, e.g. `VBox Headless.exe`, since that would require quotes and be recognised as a title.

---

Overall, the first (explicit title) method is probably better. It was a bad design choice on the part of Microsoft, they really should have added a switch for title rather than "is the first argument enclosed in quotes?".

Comment: Thanks very much for that :) Although as I see know `start /b` don't put the virtual machine in the background. I have to come up with something else then.

Comment: If you just want to suppress output (`stdout`), add a `>nul` to the end. Use `>nul 2>nul` at the end to suppress both normal output and error (`stderr`) output. The command prompt window has to be kept open, however.

Comment: @Patryk If you don't mind using PowerShell, this command will open a windowless process that isn't connected to the spawning (powershell.exe) process. Therefore the PowerShell window can be closed and VBoxHeadless will keep running. PowerShell comes with Windows 7. `Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe' -ArgumentList '-startvm "debian604 64"' -WindowStyle Hidden`

Answer (score 4):

Actually the accepted answer is still not a solution. Closing the cmd window where the command was executed in will kill the vboxheadless process with the running virtual machine in it.

Using the approach below will make [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) run an independent process.

In cmd, run:

```
cd "c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox"
vboxmanage list vms
```

This will return something like:

```
"Webserver LAP" {8748b594-7e2d-4d8d-8785-999940766754}
```

Now take the UUID and run the following (still in cmd):

```
powershell start-process 'C:\program files\oracle\virtualbox\vboxheadless' '-s 8748b594-7e2d-4d8d-8785-999940766754' -WindowStyle Hidden
```

Thanks to the author of [this article](http://www.thatsgeeky.com/2012/03/windowless-virtualbox-vms-windows-host/#comment-2134).

Comment: In [my comment on my own answer](http://superuser.com/questions/413939/how-to-start-a-program-with-command-line-arguments-on-windows-cmd-with-start#comment472639_413966) I've already provided an alternative method for "running VBox headlessly". My answer itself addresses the question of "passing arguments with `start`".

Comment: WOW! `cd` SAVED MY HOURS!