# How to make a Start Screen icon for Notepad that will always open a new Notepad when clicked in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, start-screen

Just installed Windows 8, pinned Notepad to the start screen. When I press the Windows key and use the Notepad tile to run Notepad, it will focus on the currently open Notepad window. I'd like it to start a new instance of Notepad. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It actually is possible with a reg key to do this.  it only works for desktop apps (not full screen win8 apps) though i imagine this is exactly what everyone is looking to do.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\Launcher]
"DesktopAppsAlwaysLaunchNewInstance"=dword:00000001
```

Source [here](http://teamwindows8.com/2013/04/launch-multiple-instances-of-app-from-start-screen-in-windows-8/).

Comment: Hmmpf, seems that it dosent work for me. Too bad.

Comment: My searches indicate that this does not work in 8,1. The middle click suggested by ronalchn does.

Comment: Doesn't work in Server 2012

Answer (score 17):

Use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to start a new instance of any application. Either <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-Click, or else **middle click**.

Source: http://codeyarns.com/2012/10/22/start-multiple-instances-of-an-application-in-windows-8/

Other taskbar modifiers include:

```
Shift+Click         Open a new instance of the program
Ctrl+Click          Cycle between windows in a group
Middle Click        Open a new instance of the program
Ctrl+Shift+Click    Open a new instance of the program as Administrator
Shift+Right-Click   Show window menu
```

Comment: Came here to say this, I always use Middle-Click to open a new instance, it works in Windows 7 too.

Comment: Ctrl-click is the greatest thing ever! Thank you!

Comment: Microsoft should've made this more visible. I've searched for standard windows hotkeys and never found these earlier. Will use these a lot from now on.

Answer (score 13):

To make it *always* open a new window with a normal left click, change the shortcut target of the tile:

1. Right click on the tile
2. `Open file location`. A File Explorer window should open, with a `Notepad` shortcut in it
3. Right click on the `Notepad` shortcut
4. Click properties
5. Change the target to `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start %windir%\system32\notepad.exe`

   [image]

Comment: This works for programs that have no spaces in the path but not for something like Wordpad.exe. For that I use `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start /d "%ProgramFiles%\Windows NT\Accessories" wordpad.exe`. Because the path has spaces it needs quoted, but if `start` sees quotes in the first argument it treats it as the title of the new window. Here I use the `/d` switch to specify the (quoted) path for the executable separately from the executable name. This works better for me than shift-clicking which can put new windows behind everything else--so far all new windows are on top.

Comment: @User5910 You could (should) just put a set of empty quotes for the title - the `/d` method will fail if the executable name itself has spaces. I've actually answered a question [addressing that very issue](http://superuser.com/a/413966/117590).

Answer (score 3):

Another rather tedious way to go about it is to right click on the tile & select "Open in New Window"

Comment: In fact, this is usually the quickest way (for me) to make a new instance of an already running app. Opening the Start Screen, finding the app (however conveniently placed it may be) and Shift-Clicking it seems needlessly complicated (though I'm glad I've learned of it) compared to right-clicking the taskbar and clicking on "New whatever".