# How to make Windows 8 Start Screen search result icon to open a new instance of a Desktop App

Tags: windows-8, search, start-screen

There is a registry hack that makes Windows 8/8.1 Start Screen Tiles to open a new instance of a Desktop App (see accepted answer of this question: [How to make a Start Screen icon for Notepad that will always open a new Notepad when clicked in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/493813/how-to-make-a-start-screen-icon-for-notepad-that-will-always-open-a-new-notepad))

Unfortunately this doesn't apply to the search results in the Start Screen. Is there a (registry) hack so that when I hit the Windows key, type "note" and press Enter to open the first result (usually notepad.exe) and Windows opens a new instance, just like it does in Windows 7?

Comment: I know this is old, but just wondering what it is you're trying to do that John's answer doesn't work for you. Were you just trying to keep from having to press Shift out of principal (I wouldn't blame you) or did you have some sort of automated task that relied on this feature?

Comment: @BVernon: Yes, I want this functionality without pressing SHIFT + ENTER. Just type the program name and press ENTER to open the desired app (but a new instance).

Answer (score 3):

While this isn't exactly what you asked for, you can use

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open a new instance.

Comment: Yes I was aware of this workaround, but it isnt's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I've been right clicking on the taskbar icon all this time to get a new instance to open. It's been suuuper annoying not to be able to just ctl-esc and type notepad to open a new instance. Thanks!!