# How to set a permanent Affinity Mask

Tags: windows-7, intel-core-i7

How can I set affinity mask for all of my cores on an i7 6700k on a certain program, I know you can do it through Task Manager but that is only temporary and resets after the program is shut down.

Thanks

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/602837/set-default-processor-affinity-for-all-applications?rq=1

Comment: @Ramhound, I heard there was a way that you could do it by editing the target field in the shortcut properties, I am just not sure what number I would add for all the cores rather than just an individual one

Comment: Where did you hear this?  [Start an Application Assigned to a Specific CPU in Windows 7, 8, or Vista](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/start-an-application-assigned-to-a-specific-cpu-in-windows-vista/).

Comment: That is only a single core though, is it possible to start it with multiple cores?

Comment: [processhacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) with usernotes plugin allows you to save affinity for programs and while ProcessHacker is running and you start the new tool the affinity is set to the configured value.