# Set program affinity without opening the task manager in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, cpu, affinity

Is it possible to set program affinity without opening the task manager in Windows 8.1 using the program shortcut? (by using a command like -setaffinity)

Is this method (changing affinity) a good way of limiting a program's CPU usage?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/309617/how-to-limit-a-process-to-a-single-cpu-core

Comment: Also: http://superuser.com/search?tab=votes&q=windows%20affinity%20is%3aq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a batch file with

```
start /affinity 1 PATH_TO_EXE.exe
```

Just call this batch file in your shotcut. This will run it with only CPU 0. Change the affinity mask (this is the hex value) for more cores.

```
CPU3 CPU2 CPU1 CPU0  Bin  Hex
---- ---- ---- ----  ---  ---
OFF  OFF  OFF  ON  = 0001 = 1
OFF  OFF  ON   OFF = 0010 = 2
OFF  OFF  ON   ON  = 0011 = 3
OFF  ON   OFF  OFF = 0100 = 4
OFF  ON   OFF  ON  = 0101 = 5 
OFF  ON   ON   OFF = 0110 = 6
OFF  ON   ON   ON  = 0111 = 7
ON   OFF  OFF  OFF = 1000 = 8
ON   OFF  OFF  ON  = 1001 = 9
ON   OFF  ON   OFF = 1010 = A 
ON   OFF  ON   ON  = 1011 = B
ON   ON   OFF  OFF = 1100 = C
ON   ON   OFF  ON  = 1101 = D
ON   ON   ON   OFF = 1110 = E 
ON   ON   ON   ON  = 1111 = F
```

(Thanks to @Mokubai for pointing this out)

Alternatively, create a shortcut to

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start /affinity 1 PATH_TO_EXE.exe
```

Comment: Given that the "start" command CPU affinity is a bit mask (http://superuser.com/a/309663/19943) simply increasing the value would be problematic and produce unexpected results in many cases.

Comment: Looks invalid syntax to me, you missing a "", which when not present simply opens a cmd prompt, and also /affinity flag seems to be ignored in latest builds of 10 and 11.