# Task Affinity on <all processors> after starting with /affinity F on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, affinity

I am trying to start an application with a specific affinity because I need it for some experiments. To achieve this, I am trying to set the affinity when starting the application. For this I use the command following the post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1173845/set-program-affinity-without-opening-the-task-manager-in-windows-8-1):

```
start /affinity F SnapperServer.exe
```

On my local computer this works perfectly. However, on my instance in Amazon E2C this has no effect on the processor affinity. When I go to **Task Manager -> Details -> (Right click) Set Affinity** and check if the affinity has been set, I can see that it is not:

[image]

Does anybody know why this works locally, but not in the cloud ?

--

Instance Details: I am using a c5.9xlarge instance in eu-north-1 region.

Windows_Server-2022-English-Full-Base-2023.07.12

Virutalization Method: hvm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set program affinity without opening the task manager in Windows 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/1173845/set-program-affinity-without-opening-the-task-manager-in-windows-8-1)

Comment: No it does not because I am already doing what is instructed in this post. It is a bit weird because the same execution on my local computer starts the application with 4 cores, but inside the cloud computer it does not. I think there might be some configuration problem in the cloud.

Comment: If you do something like 0x1 instead what happens?

Comment: On my local computer it starts correctly with one cpu, in the cloud it is on <All processors>

Comment: I adjusted the question upon your comments, thx!

Comment: Provide more information about the Windows environment in question.

Comment: Is this issue due to how the cloud nature of this system may differ from a physical machine?

Comment: I added information about the windows server and the instance in the question.

Comment: @music2myear I thought about that too, but I am not aware of what could be the potential difference.