# PermissionError: The process cannot access file because being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\scipy-36p0uzzx'

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, python

I'm using an open-source program that runs through thousands of operations in sequence and "scipy" is one of the libraries being used. At some random iteration, I get this error and the process dies leaving me to find out the process I wanted to run overnight doesn't.

It makes no sense though. How is this file blocking itself? I have Windows 11, Windows Defender, Malwarebytes Anti-exploit... I don't know which if any could be causing the problem. The files truly are temporary because when I go to find them after the crash, they're not even there so there's no way to know what is using them in the first place.

If I watch the temp folder, I can see files of that naming convention appear and disappear at unknown intervals. When it does show up, it disappears again almost instantly.

Comment: You say you cannot see the file(s), try a command prompt with administrative privs. Go to the folder 'temp' and type attrib *

Answer (score 0):

Windows allows an application to be [multithreaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture)). That means that a single application can spawn multiple threads. So, when you state, " At some random iteration, I get this error," it implies that one thread is blocking another, hogging a needed resource, i.e., *scipy-36p0uzzx*. Thic is called [thread contention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970345/what-is-thread-contention).

Normally, a well-written multithreaded application uses a method to indicate a resource is in use, such as a [mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524/what-is-a-mutex), to avoid contention.

If the application you are using fails because of contention, then try to limit the number of threads.

- If the app has such a setting, perhaps in an .ini file, set it to single threading.
- If it is an *interpreted* app, e.g., running in Java, it might be possible to instruct the engine to limit number of threads.
- You can try to limit the number of *CPU cores* the process uses [by setting Affinity](https://superuser.com/questions/309617/how-to-limit-a-process-to-a-single-cpu-core).
- Contact the app developers for help. My experience has been that developers of open-source projects are *more responsive* to user requests than those of commercial applications.

Comment: Interesting. It's python, but as you said I can try contacting the app developer. He's already told me that I'm the only person who's had the problem so far and suggested it might be Windows, anti-virus etc. That's why I was hoping to find a different possibility here. Still might be multithreading as you said.

Comment: Doesn't look like i have an affinity option in task manager.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053671/python-how-do-you-stop-numpy-from-multithreading , and for developer, https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-concurrency/python-threading-lock/